# Changing the font size in a DAG in R

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm building a Bayesian network (DAG) in R, it has several nodes stemming from one parent, so it has a lot of nodes.
I can't seem to figure out how to increase the font size of the node labels (won't let me post image).

To plot it, I've just done plot(dag_pigment).

Where the input is this:

```
dag_pigment<-dag(c("pigment","1800407"),c("pigment","12203592"),c("pigment","12896399"),c("pigment","3829241"),c("3829241","12913832"), c("pigment","1408799"), c("1408799", "12913832"),c("pigment","683"),c("pigment","10777129"),c("pigment", "28777"),c("pigment", "16891982"),c("pigment", "6119471"), c("pigment", "1426654"),c("pigment", "1800414"),c("pigment", "4959270"),c("pigment", "2378249"),c("pigment", "12821256"),c("pigment", "1805007"))
```

I've tried using cex within the plot function, and all the other subcategories (cex.main, cex.sub,etc.)
I've tried using ps, and I've tried using par like par(ps=20,cex=1,cex.main=1).

Are there other functions I should be trying? A different plot function?

Appreciate any help!  I'm still pretty new at figuring these things out.

Comment: Where does the `dag` function come from? Its not base R and its not in the `igraph` package...

Comment: It's a part of the gRbase package, which looks specific to making this type of graph

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually figured this out after several hours, so, I'm posting the answer to be helpful for anyone else who might be looking.

You have to use the attrs function:

```
dag_pigment.cust<-plot(dag_pigment,attrs=list(node=list(fontsize=60)))
```

and this increased the font.